# What is the best way to cast in C++?

Tags: c++, casting

What is the best way to cast from `complex` to `int` in C++?

Comment: What output do you expect out of your complex as a result of casting?

Comment: he probably meant complex number

Comment: What result are you going to get from, say, 1+2j ?

Comment: There's no such thing as _best_

Comment: Funny how questions like this one doesn't get votes for closing. Is it too broad, vague, impossible to answer objectively, too open etc? But my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691266/which-team-is-right-visual-studio-or-gcc, got closed. Interesting.

Comment: -1 for a question so vague that it is not possible to answer

Comment: @There: Give it time. You can count on impossibly vague questions being closed.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer your question since there isn't, in general, a way to do this.  Mathematically speaking, what does it mean to cast a complex number (a + bi) to a real number (a + 0i)?  You could drop the complex term, or restrict yourself to the case where b = 0, I suppose; this first option seems inelegant and the second option doesn't always work.

The second problem you'll have to address is that in C++ the `complex` template exists for `float`, `double`, and `long double`, none of which have lossless conversions to `int`.  So I suppose that if you work out the details of the first part, you'd then have to ensure that the rest of the cast is still valid.

If what you want to do is extract the real component from a `complex`, you can do this:

```
complex<double> myComplex = /* ... */
double real = myComplex.real();
```

and then possibly

```
int realInt = static_cast<int>(real);
```

Comment: You can also compute the absolute value of (a + bi), which is probably what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload  operator int ();